# Error message with SOAPUI

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I tried to run the below envelope in SOAPUI. This is a SOAP Webservice call. The SOAP UI software I am using is an OPEN source. This is giving an error message

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://siebel.com/WebService">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <web:CreateSR_Input>
     <web:UserPriority>?</web:UserPriority>
     <web:SubArea2>?</web:SubArea2>
     <web:UNINOnBehalfEmailAddr>?</web:UNINOnBehalfEmailAddr>
     <web:AssetType>?</web:AssetType>
     <web:PointofContact>?</web:PointofContact>
     <web:TargetResolutionDate>?</web:TargetResolutionDate>
     <web:ReportedByMissionID>?</web:ReportedByMissionID>
     <web:SRTemplate>?</web:SRTemplate>
     <web:AlternateContactName>?</web:AlternateContactName>
     <web:AlternateServiceLocation>?</web:AlternateServiceLocation>
     <web:OnBehalfOfBadge>?</web:OnBehalfOfBadge>
     <web:ReportedByIndex>?</web:ReportedByIndex>
     <web:SRAssignedToGroup>?</web:SRAssignedToGroup>
     <web:SRType>?</web:SRType>
     <web:SubmitEmail>?</web:SubmitEmail>
     <web:SubArea3>?</web:SubArea3>
     <web:Serial>?</web:Serial>
     <web:Urgency>?</web:Urgency>
     <web:Barcode>?</web:Barcode>
     <web:Title>?</web:Title>
     <web:ActualStartDate>?</web:ActualStartDate>
     <web:SRAssignedToID>?</web:SRAssignedToID>
     <web:AlternatePhone>?</web:AlternatePhone>
     <web:AssetAdditionalComments>?</web:AssetAdditionalComments>
     <web:Impact>?</web:Impact>
     <web:OnBehalfOfIndex>?</web:OnBehalfOfIndex>
     <web:SubArea>?</web:SubArea>
     <web:Area>?</web:Area>
     <web:UNINRequestorEmailAddr>?</web:UNINRequestorEmailAddr>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <web:RFOrgName>?</web:RFOrgName>
     <web:AssetModel>?</web:AssetModel>
     <web:FileAttachments>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <web:FileAttachment>
           <web:FileName>?</web:FileName>
           <web:FileExt>?</web:FileExt>
           <web:FileBase64>?</web:FileBase64>
        </web:FileAttachment>
     </web:FileAttachments>
     <web:ReportedByBadge>?</web:ReportedByBadge>
     <web:RequestedItem>?</web:RequestedItem>
     <web:AssetMake>?</web:AssetMake>
     <web:ReferenceNum>?</web:ReferenceNum>
     <web:Source>?</web:Source>
     <web:SubArea1>?</web:SubArea1>
     <web:AlternateEmailAddress>?</web:AlternateEmailAddress>
     <web:Description>?</web:Description>
     <web:OnBehalfOfMissionID>?</web:OnBehalfOfMissionID>
     <web:ServiceLocation>?</web:ServiceLocation>
     <web:Severity>?</web:Severity>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <web:Region>?</web:Region>
     <web:AssetNum>?</web:AssetNum>
  </web:CreateSR_Input>
   </soapenv:Body> 
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get the below error Response. Did I send any parameter wrong? Can you please let mw know what additionally I need to add. Thanks in advance

```
          <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Error Code: 10944642 Error Message: Error: Inbound SOAP Message - Session Token is missing or invalid or has expired</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <siebelf:errorstack xmlns:siebelf="http://www.siebel.com/ws/fault">
           <siebelf:error>
              <siebelf:errorsymbol/>
              <siebelf:errormsg>Error: Inbound SOAP Message - Session Token is missing or invalid or has expired</siebelf:errormsg>
           </siebelf:error>
        </siebelf:errorstack>
     </detail>
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Error message clearly says what the problem is.

Comment: @krish mandava your header `<soapenv:Header/>` should be `</soapenv:Header>` and there should be an opening tag for header.

Comment: @user1207289, what you said is incorrect. And the author has it right. The issue is it is expecting security token along with request.

Comment: @krish mandava, did it resolve the issue?